# I did not understand use of patch command in Linux

Tags: linux

I am really did not understand use of patch              command
             I have file1 with 1  2 3
            file2 with 1  2 4 
             diff -u file1 file2 > out.patch
             patch -b file1 out.patch
   Now file1 will have 1  2  4 ... Is it a copy file2 or what?
What is happening here or what s the use of patch command

Comment: Have you tried `man patch`?

Comment: do you know what's a patch file?

Answer (score 3):

`man patch` says

> patch takes a patch file patchfile containing a difference listing
>   produced by the diff program and applies those differences to one or
>   more original files, producing patched versions.
>   Normally the patched versions are put in place of the originals.
>   Backups can be made; see the -b or --backup option.

So, in your case `diff -u file1 file2` results in the difference between two files which is `4` in this case; then `patch` command applies that difference to the original file.

> Is it a copy file2 or what?

It will not be but rather appending the difference of files to the original file.